# apply filter to gcloud sql

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to filter a fleet of `cloudsql` instances based on if they have a recommendation using gcloud cli.

For example I want to list the all the instances that are nearing storage capacity.

I tried this but no luck:

```
➜ gcloud sql instances list --project <project-name> --filter='recommendations:on'

➜ gcloud sql instances list --project <project-name> --filter='recommendations:*'
WARNING: The following filter keys were not present in any resource : recommendations
Listed 0 items.
```

[image]

Any help please?

Comment: Can you try to use `--filter='recommendations~.*'`? (Regex syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Recommender [API](https://cloud.google.com/recommender/docs/overview) through the gcloud CLI to work directly with these recommendations for your instances. In this case, try using the `gcloud recommender recommendations list` [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/recommender/recommendations/list) and passing the `--recommender=RECOMMENDER` flag with any of the available Cloud SQL [recommendations](https://cloud.google.com/recommender/docs/recommenders) (including [out of disk](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/using-ood-recommender)):

```
gcloud recommender recommendations list --project=PROJECT_ID --location=LOCATION --recommender=google.cloudsql.instance.RECOMMENDER
```

Adding more context for `gcloud sql instances list`, the available filters for any given `gcloud` command can be seen by sampling the YAML output (using `--format=yaml`), as noted in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters#:%7E:text=Determine%20which%20fields%20are%20available%20for%20filtering). I tried it, but recommendation data is not returned as an available property.

Comment: @DevBabai if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I ended following this approach. Thank you!